# From where can i get the stake address while integrating cardano blockchain with flutter using blockfrost

Tags: wallet, cardano-node, cardano-address

I am using this package https://pub.dev/packages/blockfrost to integrate the Cardano smart contract with my Flutter application. I want anyone can log in to the app and interact with the contract so I will not pass a static stake address in the following api call .
[image]